# how can I get the current Bearer token of my request?

Tags: java, spring, feign

I am trying to do something relatively simple.

I have a request that receives an oauth token `(Bearer asdf22324...)` I need it to pass it to my feign client to be able to request another service using the same token.

Is it possible to do that? Any ideas/examples?

I have tried this way:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
ResponseEntity<Void> loginUser(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

But authHeader is always empty...

I also tried the interceptor, but I'm not sure how it would affect others (and not sure how to invoke it either).

[Feign Client - Dynamic Authorization Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168320/feign-client-dynamic-authorization-header)

Ideas?

Comment: The `@RequestHeader` at feign interface successfully add header for me. check some where else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you can try implementing the `Filter` (say `TokenFilter`) and inside it you can read the `Authorization` header from the `HttpServletRequest` and extract the token.

```
String authTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

// parse the token
// there can be type of token passed. So you may need to take the substring after the type and the whitespace. Eg: Bearer <TOKEN>
```

Comment: Please note that request.getHeader("Authorization") may not return only token string, but also the type of token at the beginning, something like: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSl..."